# how to handle errors in multiple async await whle promise rejected without using try catch blocks?

Tags: node.js, express

i am new to express and was making user signup api. In this i need to hash user password and generate a random string. these both things are done by aync/await.If one promise got rejected then it returns the response in error handling but shows me warning for unhandled rejected promise.

```
methods.signup = async (req,res,next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(config.errorCodes.validation).json({errors:errors.array()});
    }
    let payload = req.body;
    var newUser = new User({
        username:payload.username,
        fullname:payload.fullname,
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password,
        urltoken:{
            token:null
        },
        actStatus: 0,
        provider: 'email',
       role:1
    });
    let hash = commonMethods.generatePasswordHash(payload.password);
    let token = commonMethods.createRandomString();

    let [a,b] = await Promise.all([hash,token]).catch(err=>{
        res.status(400).json({status:false,msg:"error in promise"})
     });

    newUser.password = a;
    newUser.urltoken.token = b;
    newUser.save(function(err){
        if(err) {
            return res.status(config.errorCodes.success).json({ status:false 
        ,msg:"Error in saving userdata. Please try again",err});
        }
        else {
            commonMethods.sendMail(newUser);
            return res.status(config.errorCodes.success).json({"status":true, 
        "msg":"Registered succesfully. Please Check your Email to verify 
        your account.",newUser})
    }
}); 
}
```

and promise are -

```
commonMethods.createRandomString = function(password){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 25;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
   reject(randomstring);
   // resolve(randomstring);

})
}
```

which is always rejected for creating error.

Here is get below error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:15172) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

how to catch these errors without using try catch or then for promises and keeping my code simple and easy to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the lines

```
let [a,b] = await Promise.all([hash,token]).catch(err=>{
  res.status(400).json({status:false,msg:"error in promise"})
});
```

If either `hash` or `token` throw, then the `.catch` function is entered, but the `catch` function doesn't return anything: so, after the `await` and `catch` have finished, the interpreter will see something like

```
let [a,b] = undefined
```

which won't work (`undefined` is not iterable), so the whole `.signup` method rejects. You need some way for the rest of the `signup` function to know to stop executing if there was an error in `hash` or `token`, maybe something like

```
const result = await Promise.all([hash,token]).catch(err=>{
  res.status(400).json({status:false,msg:"error in promise"})
});
if (!result) return;
let [a,b] = result;
```

You say you don't want to use `try`/`catch`, but the logic might be a bit easier to follow that way, since you could `return` immediately from inside the `catch`:

```
let a, b;
try {
  ([a, b] = await Promise.all([hash,token]));
} catch(e) {
  return res.status(400).json({status:false,msg:"error in promise"});
}
```

Comment: or can we try if promise always returns resolve object with error property and data . and then we can check for a.err && b.err ? which will be better coding?

Comment: In making Apis, which will be better approach using async/await or using promise/ .then ? 
As async await makes more cleaner and better understanding code and promise/then makes lengthy code !

Comment: You could do `.catch(err => err)` and then check `result instanceof Error` if you wanted. It's up to you, I don't have a preference (even though I *usually* have a preference when it comes to code style :) )

Comment: Both `.then`s and `await`s can result in shorter code in different situations.

Comment: - situations like if we have dependent chain of promises.. then we should use _.then_ and if we need independent results with promises, we can use async/await ?

Comment: I'd prefer `await` when there's more than one Promise that needs to be resolved *serially*, because it makes the code a lot flatter. But when there's just one, IMO `try { await <something> } catch(e) { handle err }` isn't really better than `<something>.then().catch()`. Often you can avoid having to handle errors in the *producer function* at all by letting the consumer handle it. eg `methods.signup().catch(() => res.status(400).json({status:false,msg:"error in promise"}); );` or something of the sort. This way you don't have to do any error handling in `signup`

Comment: great ! your solution worked perfectly. thanks for all answers

Answer (score 1):

***Coding Convention Suggestion for API***

**1)** There are two ways to handle errors neatly. The first one is by wrapping all the async routes with a try catch block which will handle both synchronous and asynchronous code errors.

**Async/Await**

```
methods.foo = async(req, res, next) => {
try {
    // assuming bizz is a utility analogous to createRandomString
    // and returns a promise object which will either get resolved or rejected
    // if resolved the response will end in this case and end the response
    // if rejected, await will throw an error which will be caught by the catch block
    var bar = await bizz(); // Asynchronous code(which will wait for a promise to be resolved)

    // {... DO SYNCHRONOUS STUFF ...}

    // if suppose there is an error in your synchronous code,
    // then it will throw an error which also will  be caught by the catch block
    res.end();
} catch (err) {
    // {... DO WHAT YOU NEED TO WITH THE ERROR CAUGHT BY EITHER Asynchronous OR Synchronous part of the method ...}
    console.log(err);
    res.end(err);
  }
}
```

**2)** The second way is to have a middleware that wraps all the routes so that rewriting try catch for all the routes is avoided. Here both synchronous and asynchronous errors will be handled by the .catch() part in the async Middleware.

**Using Async Await Middleware**

```
const asyncMiddleware = (asyncFunction) => {
return (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(asyncFunction(req, res, next))
    .catch((err) => {
        // DO STUFF WITH ERROR
        res.end(err);
    });
  }
};
methods.foo = asyncMiddleware((req, res, next) => {
  // assuming bizz is a utility analogous to createRandomString
  // and returns a promise object which will either get resolved or rejected
  // if resolved the response will end in this case and end the response
  // if rejected, await will throw an error which will be caught by asyncMiddleware
  var bar = await bizz(); // Asynchronous code(which will wait for a promise to be resolved)

  // {... DO SYNCHRONOUS STUFF ...}
  // if suppose there is an error in your synchronous code
  // then it will throw an error which also will be caught by asyncMiddleware
  res.end();
});
```

Comment: nice. but i didn't understood second way .!

Comment: The Async Middleware serves as a wrapper for every route. For example, if you have 5 routes in your application, as per the first approach we need to handle the errors within a try catch block for every route. Instead let's say we wrap it around a middleware. Now every call to this route will be served by the middleware. So the middleware itself accepts an asyncFunction which will essentially be an express route and wraps it inside a promise. If some error is thrown in the route either by Promise Rejection or synchronous part, the .catch part in the asyncMiddleware will handle both the errors.